# Best way to integrate javascript app in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, html

My project is to make a website with html5 games, in Rails.

I have a controller called `games_controller`, and I would like to match */games/name-of-my-game* with each html5 games. I created a route, matched with a games_controller function, but here is my problem:

I want everything to be "plug-and-play" for my html5 games, I mean develop them out-of-Rails, then just copy/paste it inside my app and everything works fine (references to images,.js files and all). But I also want my game's view to be inside my application layout. Here is what I tried :

- Put it in */public* directory, and in my games_controller's `show` method do `render "/public/path_to_my_game"`. This breaks all references like `<script type="text/javascript" src="some_script.js"></script>`, cause the url isn't */path_to_my_game* but */games/name-of-my-game*.
- Put it in */public* directory, but with a `redirect_to` in my `show` method instead `render`. The references are not broken, but the layout is gone (I may be wrong, but layouts are stuck with controllers, not static files).
- Put it in *app/views/games* but this seemed ugly so I quickly stopped :).

Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: if you're only using rails as a basic layout wrapper and router, I'd strongly suggest checking out [Sinatra](http://sinatrarb.com).

Comment: having you tried putting in app\assets\javascripts and using a javascript_include_tag ?

Comment: macek: To be honnest I already have a part of this website made, so I'll stick to rails now (and I wanted to learn the technology ^^)
AntarrByrd: As my comment to macek's post, I'd like to avoid as much as I can to split up my games' logic (some files in one folder, some files in another one...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have something like

```
# config/routes.rb
match '/games/:game' => 'games_controller#show'

# app/controllers/games_controller.rb
def show
  @game = params[:game]
end
```

All you really have to do in your layout file is

```
<%= javascript_include_tag @game %>
```

This means you will have a `app/assets/javascripts/<game>.js` file for each game you have. It will be responsible for booting each game.

Obviously, you will want to take precaution to validate that `params[:game]` is a valid game.

---

Alternatively, you could create a content section in your layout file

```
<html>
  <head>
    <%= yield :game %>
  </head>
  <!-- rest of layout ... -->
```

Then serve the appropriate view with your `GamesController`

```
# app/controllers/games_controller.rb
def show
  @game = params[:game]
  render "games/#{@game}"
rescue ActionView::MissingTemplate
  redirect_to root_path, :alert => "invalid game id"
end
```

Then in your game views, you will require all necessary files for each game. For example, a user visits `/games/pacman`

```
# app/views/games/pacman.html.erb
<% content_for :game do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'pacman/foobar' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'pacman/start' %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'pacman/styles' %>
<% end %>
```

Another example, user visits `/games/time_pilot`

```
# app/views/games/pacman.html.erb
<% content_for :game do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'time_pilot/init' %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'time_pilot/base' %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'time_pilot/retro' %>
<% end %>
```

Because I'm sure each game is going to have a different amount of dependencies and they will all be initialized differently, you can build the view for each game accordingly and serve up whatever assets are relevant to each game.

---

Fore more help with with layouts and rendering, see the rails guide: [Layouts and Rendering in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-the-content_for-method)

Comment: Thanks for such a complete answer :). I'll try this as soon as I can, even if that's not 100% what I want. It does not suit the "plug-and-play" part, as I have to create a .html.erb file (rails-only) and I have to split .js in assets/js, .css in assets/stylesheets,... Putting all in /public was fine for me, as it's like moving all in one block. Aren't there any solutions with /public directory ? Something bad with this approach ?